# is a null set the same as {}

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

Ø vs set {}:

Ø has no elements

whereas {} has the null set as an element; that is, say you are making power set of {}: Ø would be an element of the power set or in symbols, P({}): {Ø}

right? I feel these distinctions might come into play in certain problems I come across; they are confusing and I am looking for clarification

I ask because I do not think Ø = {}

Comment: Both mean the same.

Comment: so P(Ø) is also {Ø}?

Comment: @TrevorLe $\emptyset$ has the same number of elements as $\{\}$ which is $0$. They are different notations to represent the same thing.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209063/is-the-empty-set-a-power-set

Comment: ok. much appreciation.

Comment: $\{\}$ does not have the empty set as an element; it has no elements (since there is nothing between the braces)

Comment: textbook says  P(Ø): {Ø} as all sets have the Ø as a element of the power set; so your are saying Ø is not an implicit element of {} even if Ø is a element of the power set of {}?

Comment: It is worth reminding that $\{\emptyset\} = \{~\{\}~\}\neq \{~\} = \emptyset$.  The set on the far left has one element while the set on the right does not have any elements.

Comment: yes that seems right JM

Comment: "An element of the power set" does not mean "an implicit element"(whose meaning is unclear to me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When one doubts whether a given set is equal to "another" set, one can use the axiom of extentionnality ( the definition of set equality) according to which :

(set A = set B)  IFF ( for all x,  x belongs to A <--> x belongs to B) .

But using this axiom requires, in certain  cases, some  familiarity with the truth table of the " if...then" and  of the " <--> " operator. One has to know that, when a set S is empty, the sentence " x belongs to S" being false, any conditional  statement having the sentence " x belongs to S" as antecedent is " automatically" true ( "vacuously true" as some say pleasantly).  And notice that a biconditionnal ( " <-->" ) is simply the conjunction of two " if ...then" statements.

Here if you plug   the set Ø and the set    {  } in the formula of the axiom of extentionnality, you will see you will get a statement that is vacuously true ( in both directions). So your "two" sets pass the test of equality: they are, in fact, exactly the same set.

If you are not acquainted  with the " if... then" or " iff" operator, **rephrase the principle of extensionnality**, and say that a set A and a set B are equal just in case :

(1) there is no object that belongs to A and that does not belong to B 
AND 
(2) there is no object that belongs to B and that does not belong to A.

So **can you see an object that belongs to Ø and does not belong to {  } ? and can you see an object that belongs to {  } but does not belong to Ø ?**

If you answered **"no" to both questions**, you know that : Ø = {  }  ( or, if you prefer, that : {  } = Ø ).

Comment: amazing thanks!

Comment: @Trevor Le. You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Let us make it clear by defining each set.

$1)$  The empty set $\phi$ is a set with no element. We use it for example to denote the intersection of tow disjoint sets.

$2)$ $\{\}$ is another way to show the empty set so it does not have any element.

$3)$ $\{\phi\}$ is a set which has one element and that one element is the empty set.

$4)$ The power set of the empty set $P(\phi)$ is the set of subsets of the empty set. That is $\{\phi\}$ the same as the set in $3)$

Comment: looks good to me thanks

Comment: @TrevorLe If you like the answer, then accept it by clicking the check mark to the left. Wait a little while before doing that to see if other answers come in, though.

Comment: ahhh thanks I am new to this site