# Prove that for any set A, A = $\cup$ $\mathscr{P}$(A)

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification

**Prove that for any set A, A = $\cup$$\mathscr{P}$(A)**

I am having trouble with determining what my goal should be. On the one hand, I could prove $$A \subseteq \cup \mathscr{P}(A) \land \cup \mathscr{P}(A) \subseteq A$$  Or, $$ \forall A \forall x (x \in A 
\iff x \in \cup \mathscr{P}(A))$$

My issue is that proving the first goal suggests that I only must assume an arbitrary element of A  (and then an arbitrary element of $\cup$$\mathscr{P}(A)$) and not also an arbitrary set A. Now if the question is asking to show this relation for *any* set A, must I not make it clear that I assuming some arbitrary set A? Thus, the second goal seems more appropriate. However, if it may be assumed that A is arbitrary, I suppose the first goal will be fine. My issue is that I cannot tell if that assumption is appropriate.

Comment: You can take a set $A$, and generalize over it's elements, it's as good as generalizing the set itself, since these elements make up the set. Consider "$A$" to be just a placeholder to make notation convenient

Comment: I think I see what you're saying. To suppose x is an arbitrary element of A implies A is arbitrary. Correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was getting at

Comment: @TimmyChyrklund Not quite. The question asks you to prove this for all possible $A$. Thus what you first do is select an arbitrary set $A$. If you can prove the statement for an arbitrary / general set, then it applies to all sets. The statement "to suppose $x$ is an arbitrary element of $A$ implies $A$ is arbitrary" does not really have any meaning. It is the same as saying, "Picking any element in $A$ implies that $A$ is any set", which is not a very sensical statement. I think the statement you want to go for is, "To suppose the elements of $A$ are arbitrary implies that $A$ is arbitrary".

Comment: @Quotable Could I then rewrite $\forall$ A (A $\subseteq$ $\cup$ $\mathscr{P}$(A) $\land$ $\cup$ $\mathscr{P}$(A) $\subseteq$ A) and start out by assuming A to be an arbitrary set?

Comment: @TimmyChyrklund Yes. By proving something for an arbitrary set, you prove it for all sets. The idea is that your proof is independent of what $A$ is. Your proof should not depend on any facts about $A$, other than the fact that $A$ is a set. Thus your proof should be that no matter which $A$ was chosen, the argument still works.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to interpret $\cup \mathcal{P}(A)$ as the union of all the sets in $\mathcal{P}(A)$.

$\mathcal{P}(A)$ is the set of all subsets of $A$. Thus for all $x \in A$, $x \in \{x\} \in \mathcal{P}(A)$. Hence $x \in \cup \mathcal{P}(A)$.

Similarly, for all $x \in \cup \mathcal{P}(A)$, $x$ belongs to some subset $S$ of $A$. Since $x \in S \subseteq A$, then $x \in A$.

Comment: Doesn't https://math.stackexchange.com/a/209064/647765 imply that A = {} -> P(A) = {{},} != A?

Comment: @TareGaskin $P(${}$)$ = {{}} (it only contains a single element, the empty set itself). So $P(${}) $ != $ {} , but the problem asks about the union of all sets in $P(${}$)$, which does equate to the empty set.